# Future of Spring-XD

Tags: spring, spring-xd

I heared rumors that Spring XD lost development drive and focus at Spring shifts towards cloud services. Since I'm considering XD (the otehr one I consider is Apache Beam, though not yet mature enough imho), I'd like to get some facts / release plan for the future of XD instead of relying on rumors.

Comment: Explain your downvotes, please. Otherwise it looks like somebody doesn't like this question to be asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Spring XD homepage](http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/) has an announcement at the bottom of the page:

> **Announcement**
>
> Building upon [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) and [Spring Cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/) capabilities, Spring XD is actively being redesigned as [Spring Cloud Data Flow](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/) - a cloud native programming and operating model for composable message-driven microservices. For more information and the reasons behind this redesign, please refer to Spring Cloud Data Flow's [launch blog](https://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal-cloud-foundry/products/introducing-spring-cloud-data-flow).
>
> Spring XD's 1.3 GA will be the last release in the 1.x line and with this release, 1.x will be officially in maintenance mode, addressing only bug fixes.